# Using previous and next buttons to cycle through images in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, image

I'm writing a small mobile application using Javascript.

I'm making calls to a remote API that responds with some JSON formatted data. Within that data are URLs for images of products i need to display in my app. I've parsed the JSON into a JS array and now have an array of all the URLs for the images. When i first load my app i have a canvas which is used to display the first image from the array. I have two buttons, a previous and a next. I'd like to be able to cycle through the images using these buttons by using the URLs in the array to draw onto the canvas.

Any ideas?

Comment: post the urls code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like the following what you're looking for?

```js
  // Image URLs
  var imageUrls = ['http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/8b/bd/8bbd3405b0a197214e229428c23dbe60.png', 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/05/d1/05d1ba284ee1a3bfe4e0f68988baafb9.png', 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/99/4c/994c5997c7a509703cc53ec2000bb258.png', 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/59/0c/590c832e73a472c416bf9d8bfdd02a4a.png'];

  // Keep track of the index of the image URL in the array above
  var imageShownIndex = 0;

  // Create a canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = 150;
  canvas.width = 150;

  // Create a button that will load the previous image on the canvas when clicked
  var previousButton = document.createElement('button');
  previousButton.innerHTML = 'Previous Image';
  previousButton.onclick = function () {
      // Show images in a cycle, so when you get to the beginning of the array, you loop back to the end
      imageShownIndex = (imageShownIndex==0) ? imageUrls.length-1 : imageShownIndex-1;
      updateImage();
   };

  // Do same for the next button
  var nextButton = document.createElement('button');
  nextButton.innerHTML = 'Next Image';
  nextButton.onclick = function () {
    imageShownIndex = (imageShownIndex == imageUrls.length-1) ? 0 : imageShownIndex+1;
    updateImage();
   };

  document.body.appendChild(previousButton);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  document.body.appendChild(nextButton);
  
  // Show the first image without requiring a click
  updateImage();

  function updateImage() {

    // Create the Image object, using the URL from the array as the source
    // You could pre-load all the images and store them in the array, rather than loading each image de novo on a click
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageUrls[imageShownIndex];

    // Clear the canvas
    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);

    // After the image has loaded, draw the image on the canvas
    img.onload = function() {
      canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

  }
```

EDIT: Or if you have HTML elements already made, you can just use JavaScript to control the canvas. E.g.:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="previous_button" onclick="goToPreviousImage()">Previous Image</button>
    <canvas id="image_canvas" height=150, width=150></canvas>
    <button id="next_button" onclick="goToNextImage()">Next Image</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    var imageUrls = ['http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/8b/bd/8bbd3405b0a197214e229428c23dbe60.png', 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/05/d1/05d1ba284ee1a3bfe4e0f68988baafb9.png', 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/99/4c/994c5997c7a509703cc53ec2000bb258.png', 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/59/0c/590c832e73a472c416bf9d8bfdd02a4a.png'];

    var imageShownIndex = 0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('image_canvas');
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function goToPreviousImage() {
        imageShownIndex = (imageShownIndex==0) ? imageUrls.length-1 : imageShownIndex-1;
        updateImage();
     };

    function goToNextImage() {
      imageShownIndex = (imageShownIndex == imageUrls.length-1) ? 0 : imageShownIndex+1;
      updateImage();
     };
    
    updateImage();

    function updateImage() {

      var img = new Image();
      img.src = imageUrls[imageShownIndex];

      canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);

      img.onload = function() {
        canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }

    }

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: I actually have the buttons and canvas already created in a separate HTML file so i will need to adjust this so that its just a JavaScript function called when the buttons are clicked. I'm very new to JavaScript but i should be able to get my head around it. Would doing it this way be possible?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer to provide an illustration. You'll need to assign the onclick event handlers to the buttons. Here it's done right in the html, but you could also do this via JavaScript. You'll also need to retrieve the canvas element in the JavaScript--here it's done by document.getElementById.